# Junction table - EXCEPT replacement

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a relationship as seen below, Employees and Trainings,
Each Employee can participate in any training so it's a basic M:M to 1:M M:1 stuff.

[image: ERD]
I have a combo box to select an Employee, and I want two list boxes that List Completed Trainings and Available Trainings

Something like this: [image]

ANd then have two buttons that moves selected from one list box to other and changes the records accordingly.

I have made a Query to list all trainings the Employee Participated in:

```
SELECT Training.Name, Training.Trainer, Training.Cost, Training.Type, Training.[Length(Day)]
FROM Training INNER JOIN Participation ON Training.[Training ID] = Participation.Training
WHERE (((Participation.Employee)=[Forms]![Add Training 2]![cboEmp]))
ORDER BY Training.Name;
```

I have a problem with selecting all the trainings and filtering out the ones that have already been selected in the SQL query above a simple EXCEPT would work but ACCESS doesn't support it.

THis is what I want:

```
SELECT Training.Name, Training.Trainer, Training.Cost, Training.Type, Training.[Length(Day)]
FROM Training
EXCEPT
SELECT Training.Name, Training.Trainer, Training.Cost, Training.Type, Training.[Length(Day)]=
FROM Training INNER JOIN Participation ON Training.[Training ID] = Participation.Training
WHERE (((Participation.Employee)=[Forms]![Add Training 2]![cboEmp]))
ORDER BY Training.Name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `not exists` or `not in`:

```
SELECT Training.Name, Training.Trainer, Training.Cost, Training.Type, Training.[Length(Day)]
FROM Training
WHERE Training.TrainingId NOT IN (SELECT Participation.Training
                                  FROM Participation 
                                  WHERE Participation.Employee = [Forms]![Add Training 2]![cboEmp]
                                 )
ORDER BY Training.Name;
```